# Execute custom action before updating files on installer upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net, wix

I am trying to get connection string from web.config file in custom actions before installer replaces the files on upgrading my application.

I have tried to declare custom action in product.wxs file and call it in  with property: before="InstallFiles". But in this scenerio, it removes files first and then execute this custom action due to which i can't get previous web.connfig file. Therefore i get file not found exception.

```
<CustomAction Id="PrePreUpgrade" Return="check" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="PrePreUpgrade" Impersonate="no" HideTarget="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
<!--ON UPGRADE-->
  <Custom Action="PrePreUpgrade" Before="InstallFiles">WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Custom>
  <Custom Action="PreUpgrade" After="InstallInitialize" >WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Custom>
  <Custom Action="Upgrade" Before="InstallFinalize" >WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Custom>
  <Custom Action="RunOnBrowser"  After="Upgrade" >WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Custom>
 </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: You propably need `Before="RemoveExistingProducts"`, because this is when the files of the old version will be removed. You should show code of your major upgrade, because this depends on the scheduling of RemoveExistingProducts.

Comment: @zett42 This is my major upgrade.
    <MajorUpgrade AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

Comment: I have tried to do it using before removeexistingproducts but it gives error on installation.

Comment: What is the error?